# How to select from first table if ID exist in second or third table with high efficiency?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in assignment.
First table:
PATIENT:  patid, fname, lname, recordnum.
PATIENTDR:  patid,  drid,
PATIENTCLIN:  patid,  clinid.

I need to select patients by fname, or lname  if "PATID" in table "PATIENT" is found in table "PATIENTDR" if DRID="$docotr->id" OR "PATIENTCLIN" if CLINID="$clinic->clinid"

This is my query

```
SELECT t1.* FROM patient t1  
WHERE patlname like  '{$search_patlname}%' 
AND patfname like '{$search_patfname}%' 
AND 
(  
 EXISTS 
   (SELECT patid FROM patientdr t2 WHERE t2.drid = '{$doctor->id}' AND t2.patid = t1.patid) 

     OR  EXISTS 

   (SELECT patid FROM patientclin t3 WHERE t3.clinid = '{$clinic->clinid}' AND t3.patid = t1.patid) 
 ) 
LIMIT 10
```

The number of patients can be very high, data will be retrieved using ajax  and taking in consideration following note:

"SQL statements that use the EXISTS Condition in MySQL are very inefficient since the sub-query is RE-RUN for EVERY row in the outer query's table. There are more efficient ways to write most queries, that do not use the EXISTS Condition."

Is there a more efficient way to write this query, maybe i should break rules and insert patient fname and lname in tables patientdr and patientclin to reduce response time, or by limiting results to 10 rows is efficient enough ?
Thanks for all kind of help in advance.

Comment: if you inner join them and there is no match on the id's then they will not be returned in the result.  I imagine that'd be most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be solved with a simple INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM patient t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT patid 
    FROM patientdr t2 
    WHERE t2.drid = '{$doctor->id}' 
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT patid 
    FROM patientclin t3 
    WHERE t3.clinid = '{$clinic->clinid}'
) i
ON t1.patid = i.patid
WHERE patlname like  '{$search_patlname}%' 
AND patfname like '{$search_patfname}%' 
LIMIT 10
```

If you haven't read the documentation on INNER JOIN, it is worth taking the time to do so, and to play around with some queries that use it.

Good luck!

Comment: @jakebules Hm.. it seams that i am getting two patients as results, if same id is found in other two tables. Shouldn't the result be joined with this query, with only single patient as a result for one id ?

Comment: @jakebules fixed it with UNION DISTINCT, would you please update answer, thanks.